# Enforcing a narrower row height

Tags: html, css

I have this line of `HTML`:

```html
<div style=''line-height: 0.75em;min-height: 0.75em;''>&nbsp;</div>
```

The result is a line that is the same height as all other lines in the document.

How do I amend this code so that the blank line is 75% the height of all other lines?

Comment: can you share a full code so we can also see the other line and compare?

Comment: 1 double-quote <> 2 single quotes

Comment: Is the double-single-quote the actual problem here? Or is that just a simple typed-question-quickly error?

Comment: @LaurentS. apologies Laurent I should have explained the context: it is an html string within a SQL script - hence the sets of 2 single quotes. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove one of the sets of single quotes.

This:

```
<div style=''line-height: 0.75em;min-height: 0.75em;''>&nbsp;</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div style='line-height: 0.75em;min-height: 0.75em;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

```html
<div>Sample line 1</div>
<div style='line-height: 0.5em;min-height: 0.5em;'>&nbsp;</div>
<div>Sample line 2</div>
<!-- change the line-height and min-height values to see the blank line height change. -->
<!-- Also use 2 sets of single quotes to see that this results in the style attributes being ignored. -->
```